# mysql calculate two corresponding rows from different tables

Tags: mysql

I have two tables, one with number of deliveries to different stores depending on the day of week. Like this:

```
stores
store-n | mon | tue
store 1 | 0   | 2
store 2 | 1   | 1
```

And one where is shown how much of which product one deliver contains. Like this:

```
quantum
store-n | p1 | p2 |
store 1 | 20 | 15 |
store 2 | 5  | 8  |
```

I need to show how much of single product must be delivered in specific day to every stores.
Like this:

```
Count of p1 on monday:
store-n | p1*mon |
store 1 | 0      |
store 2 | 5      |

Count of p2 on tuesday:
store-n | p2*tue |
store 1 | 30     |
store 2 | 8      |
```

So the number of products is multiplied by number of delivers for each store.
I've tried this query:
`SELECT stores.store-n, (quantum.p1 * stores.mon) FROM quantum, stores`
But it seems it multiply 1st row of one table on every row in another then same for next and so on. What is the  correct way to do it?
And also in the end I need the sum of result column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your query is missing a join condition, which is resulting in a cross join between your two tables.  We could try to correct your original query, but it would be better to write it using explicit joins:

```
SELECT
    s.`store-n`,
    q.p1 * s.mon AS p1_cnt,
    q.p2 * s.tue AS p2_cnt
FROM stores s
INNER JOIN quantum q
    ON s.`store-n` = q.`store-n`;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT (store.mon * quantum.p1) AS 'p1*mon', (store.tue * quantum.p2) AS 'p2*tue' 
FROM `store` 
LEFT JOIN quantum 
ON store.store_n = quantum.store_n
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.